# How to hide all toolbars in Excel?

Tags: ms-office

I have disabled the *Formula Bar* and the *Ribbon* :

[image: Screenshot of view options]

But Excel still shows a bunch of tools at the top:

[image: Screenshot of Excel ribbon]

I want to de-clutter / simplify the view to only the data and the Menu itself . How can that be done?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I have disabled the Formula Bar and the Ribbon :", however, simply clicking on any of the _ribbon names_ on a _window_ a second time in a row hides the _ribbon_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse the ribbon by clicking on the title of a ribbon section, i.e. "Home", "Insert", "Draw", etc...

[image]

Comment: This is the way I've been doing it for years, if not decades.

Comment: that worked.  That feature should be available from the _view_ menu but it's not